# Cloud pubsub slow poll rate

Tags: google-cloud-platform, gcloud, google-cloud-pubsub

I have a pubsub topic, with one subscription, and two different subscribers are pulling from it.
Using stackdriver, I can see that the subscription has ~1000 messages.
Each subscriber runs the following poll loop:

```
client = pubsub.Client()
topic = client.topic(topic_name)
subscription = pubsub.Subscription(subscription_name)

while True:
    messages = subscription.pull(return_immediately=True, max_messages=100, client=client)
    print len(messages)
    # put messages in local queue for later processing. Those processes will ack the subsription
```

My issue is a slow poll rate - even though I have plenty of messages waiting to be polled, I'm getting only several messages each time. Also, lots of responses are back without any messages. According to stackdriver, my messages pulled rate is ~1.5 messages/sec.

I tried to use `return_immediately=False`, and it improved it a bit - the pull rate increased to ~2.5 messages/sec, but still - not the rate I would expect to have.

Any ideas how to increase pull rate? Any pubsub poll best practices?

Answer (score 2):

In order to increase your pull rate, you need to have more than one outstanding pull request at a time. How many depends on how fast and from how many places you publish. You'll need at least a few outstanding at all times. As soon as one of them returns, create another pull request. That way, whenever Cloud Pub/Sub is ready to deliver messages to your subscriber, you have requests waiting to receive messages.

Comment: That's exactly what I'm doing. When I get a pubsub message, I publish it in a local redis/rabitmq. Other processes will take it from there. I have several machines, (currently two, because they should handle that load of ~1000 messages). Each one pulls messages from the subscription, delivers it, and creates a new pull request

Comment: Besides - the subscription has ~1000 messages. Why does pull operation, with `max_messages=200` returns only several messages, and with `return_immediate=False` it might even return no messages at all?

Comment: You still need multiple pull requests outstanding at once. Having two machines won't necessarily guarantee that; they could both return at the same time and now you are in a state without any outstanding requests. When you say 1000 messages, is this in total or is that the number of messages per second?

Comment: The publish rate is about 10 messages/sec. Because of low pull rates, messages are pending in the subscription for a very long time, and it aggregates to over 1000 messages